# Should I capitalize Yes and No in "Yes or No question"?

Tags: phrases, capitalization

I want to talk about a question. There are two possible answers.

1. Yes.
2. No.

Could I refer to that as a Yes or No question, with both capitalized? Or, maybe Yes-or-No-question with hyphens?

I initially wrote: "Can you answer a yes or no question?" The lowercase letters don't seem quite right. The choices for the question I'm referring to will start with uppercase.

Comment: It's pronounced the same, no matter how you spell or punctuate it, so anything will do.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question to make it more clear that I'm concerned with capitalization not pronunciation.

Comment: How does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes%E2%80%93no_question) say handle this? [Professor Nordquist?](https://www.thoughtco.com/yes-no-question-grammar-1692617) (You can probably find other preferences if you try hard enough. But why bother?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I did look there. "Yes–no question" seems odd to me, but if that is your answer, why not put it as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Because I've close-voted as no reasonable research (linked and attributed, as required on ELU) was provided. And  in any case, the question is easily researched (not suitable for ELU) and even then subjective answers will be _fully expected_ to differ. Giving an 'answer' encourages further (ostensibly) unresearched questions. // Note that these references use 'yes-no question' unless capitalised because it starts a sentence, appears in a title etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense.